# Running Azure commands over a PSSession

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to automate uploading a blob to azure storage from my local machine and then download the blob on an Azure VM I have set up. I have everything configured and I am able to run a script locally to upload a blob. I can then RDP into the Azure VM and run and other script to download the blob. Perfect!

My problem is trying to do all of this on my local machine using PSSession or Invoke-Command. I can successfully start a PSSession to the Azure VM

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <myMachine>.cloudapp.net -Port 8888 -Credential username/password -UseSSL
```

However, when I then try to run an Azure command, such as over the PSSession

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $context
```

I get the error.

```
The term 'Get-AzureStorageBlobContent' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Though I can RDP to the Azure VM and run these commands as normal and everything works fine. (I have installed Azure Powershell SDK on both machines) I have also tried creating a New-PSSession and then using

```
Invoke-Command -Session $myNewSession -ScriptBlock {my script}
```

With the same error. Any help on the problem would me nice, thanks.

Comment: have you tried to `Import-Module Azure` before running commands in your PS Session?

Comment: Yes, no joy - I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

So, after much more research. It appears the answer is quite simple.

Enter-PSSession is intended for interactive mode only and not meant for scripting. A way around this is to create a New-PSSession and then use this with Invoke-Command

Also, Azure provide a download Uri to your blob files so you can just Invoke and web request without the need to run Azure commands

Example

```
$session  = New-PSSession -ComputerName <myMachine>.cloudapp.net -Port 8888 -Credential user/pass -UseSSL

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<myBlobFile>.blob.core.windows.net/container/file.zip -OutFile C:\path\on\remote\machine }
```

I hope this helps other people hitting this problem

EDIT: This only works if your blob is set to private - No good if you need to restrict access to your files :(